# Jquery Validate remote rule and depends if input value changed

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation plugin and have come up with a scenario I need to create a remote validation rule for.

Say I had a members form which users can edit their profile containing their email address and other info which is populated from a database. Obviously I would have checked using a remote method to check the email doesn't already exist when they registered.  The problem lies when the user doesn't want to update their email address but when saving the form, the validation will kick up a fuss saying the email already exists.

Is there a way I can call the remote method ONLY if the email address has been changed in the form.  If the email remains untouched, don't need to validate.

Here is an example of a remote method that works for something else:

```
rules: {
    something: {
        required: true,
        remote: {
            param: {
                url: '/path/to/file.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'test': $('#something').val()
                }
            },
            depends: function() {
                return $('body').hasClass('someClass');
            }
        }
    }
```

I would have thought I could put some check in the depends part of the rule that checks for a change but i don't know how i would do that

Comment: You can store old email address in a hidden field and compare it with email in textbox before validating it server side.

Answer (score 5):

1. Add a hidden field to your form and set its `value` to the original email address from the database when you load the page.  Also give it an `id` for later reference.  (*Note that the jQuery Validate plugin will ignore all hidden fields by default.  It will not be validated, so it does not need a `name` attribute.*)

   ```
   <input type="hidden" value="foo@bar.com" id="originalemail" />
   ```

   Your email address text input...

   ```
   <input type="text" value="foo@bar.com" name="emailaddress" />
   ```
2. Compare the `value` of the hidden field to the `value` of the `email` field in the `depends` option of your `remote` rule.

   ```
   rules: {
       emailaddress: {  // <- assumes 'name' of field is 'emailaddress'
           required: true,
           email: true,  // <- make sure data is a valid email address
           remote: {
               param: {
                   url: '/path/to/file.php',
                   type: 'post',
                   //data: // < do not need.  Value of 'emailaddress' is sent by default.
               },
               depends: function(element) {
                   // compare email address in form to hidden field
                   return ($(element).val() !== $('#originalemail').val());
               }
           } // close remote
       } // close emailaddress
   } // close rules
   ```

   Note that the `element` argument passed into the `depends` function represents the `emailaddress` field.

Comment: Just add a not (!) to the depends return condition and its works excellent. `return !($(element).val() === $('#originalemail').val());`

Comment: @RoyShoa, yes, the logic was backwards, but `!==` would suffice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Save your email to be compared after init of validation to global var and than compare it in `depends` with current value.